# What is the definition of period number and any relation between Abelian integral and such a kind of period number

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, reference-request

I recall there is a kind of real or complex number called period number which is defined by integral and algebraic function.But now,I search it again and again having gotten no result.Now any one can give an answer to the  definition and tell me what the relation between Abelian integral and the period numbers is

Comment: [This is a nice paper on periods of Riemann surfaces](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/kontzagi.pdf)

Comment: @Semiclassical,I can understand what you mean.Is it a topic that has never been studied?

Comment: @Semiclassical,I see,it is a URL to a paper,thank you

Comment: I have just browsed the paper,it seems that the paper just touched on some kind of algebraic function,and not all algebraic functions like what I have just mentioned in the other post are included.

Comment: That wasn't an exhaustive paper, no. Neither is [this one](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/legacy.pdf), but it may give some food for thought while you await an answer with more definitive references.

Comment: @Semiclassical,I am much obliged to you

Comment: @Semiclassical,I have just browsed the paper http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/legacy.pdf,interestingly,Prof.Griffiths has some words  that possibly is not correct.I will check it carefully again,but I am almost sure he has made a mistake